# State Preservation and Restoration UIImageView added from button event

Tags: objective-c, ios6, ios7, uikit-state-preservation

I am adding `UIImageView` on a button click. I want to restore it using `UIKit`.
I am getting restoration identifier in:

```
 - (void)decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder;
```

How can I decode this `UIImageView`?

Comment: you should encode & decode the image not imageview. in staterestoration process.

Comment: imageview in either not in my .h file nor in xib file. i am making and adding that imageview to view on button click.i need to reconstruct the imageview?

Comment: there is a solution for it to. you have to make a collection of images. encode & decode this collection. you should try this by your self.

Comment: how can i preserve the position of image views ?

Comment: you need a custom class , which will have two properties. 1st will hold the image 2nd will hold the position. make you custom object add them to mutable array & encode it . again while decoding you will get the collection of image that will hold the image & there position.  try it

Comment: how can i save image transform ? in my app user can zoom pan scale the image

Comment: then my answer should be accepted>

Comment: last question .. is that what pic collage is doing ? any guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have used this code in one of my app.

here is the encoding & decoding process

```
-(void)encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{

NSData *imageData=UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imgViewProfilePicture.image);
[coder encodeObject:imageData forKey:@"PROFILE_PICTURE"];
[super encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];
}

-(void)decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{

self.imgViewProfilePicture.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"PROFILE_PICTURE"]];
[super decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To make the state preservation and restoration work there are two steps that are always required:

- The App delegate must opt-in
- Each view controller or view to be
  preserved/restored must have a restoration identifier assigned.

You should also implement `encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:` and `decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:` for views and view controllers that require state to be saved and restored.

Add the following methods to the view controller of your `UIImageView`.

```
-(void)encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    [coder encodeObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(_imageView.image)
                 forKey:@"YourImageKey"];

    [super decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];
}

-(void)decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    _imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"YourImageKey"]];

    [super encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];
}
```

State preservation and restoration is an optional feature so you need to have the application delegate opt-in by implementing two methods:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application shouldSaveApplicationState:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application shouldRestoreApplicationState:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    return YES;
}
```

Useful article about state preservation:
http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2013/05/21/state-preservation-and-restoration.html

Comment: i am adding imageview from code its not initialized in my header file

Comment: do you think , without converting uiimage into nsdata , you can encode & decode it.

Comment: on button click
i use to do this

Comment: just declare the imageview in .h file so you can get a reference for imageview & get the current image.

Comment: uiimageview * myimage =[uiimageview alloc ]init];

Comment: in my app user can add as many images as he want to. so how can i declare them all in .h file ?